# How to stop the rsync process by system("ssh host rsync...")?

Tags: perl, ssh, rsync

I wrote like this Perl script.(`/tmp/file` is fuge)

```
system("ssh host1 'rsync -av /tmp/file host2:/tmp/'");
```

Then, I run this script, and kill by Ctrl+C.

The script has been stopped, but rsync process on host1 is still running.

How to stop the rsync process by Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
system("ssh -t host1 'rsync -av /tmp/file host2:/tmp/'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shall capture the rsync process id (PID) and kill this PID if you detect the CTRL-C interruption. Using bash scripting, you can capture the last pid by using *pid=$!*. You can detect the CTRL-C interruption (SIGINT=2) using the bash *trap* function on this signal SIGINT, like: **trap 'clean_exit' SIGINT** which start the *clean exit* function. Then you can do whatever you need within the clean exit function, like killing the previously captured PID.